# Unhandled Rejection (Syntax Error) Unexpected end of Output

Tags: reactjs

In ReactJS I got this error can't understand in which line of code there is a problem if anybody can help me to solve this problem then it's better for me. I want to Post API but in between getting output, there is a problem like this.
The Code is Below line please help me to resolve the problem.

**APP.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      token: null,
      url: null
    };

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = {
      grant_type: "password",
      username: "username",
      password: "password"
      }
    fetch('url of api',{
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      
      body: JSON.stringify(url)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ token: data.access_token }));
    // const requestOptions = {
    //   method: 'POST',
    //   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    //   body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
    // };
    // fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', requestOptions)
    //   .then(response => response.json())
    //   .then(data => this.setState({ token: data.id }));
  }
  // Simple POST request with a JSON body using fetch

  render() {

    const { token } = this.state;
    return (
      <div >
        <h5 >Simple POST Request</h5>
        <h5>{token}</h5>
      </div>

    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the **token**. So You have to render like this `{token || ' '}`.

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (Syntax Error) Unexpected end of Output, is this the only error message you are getting ?

Comment: Yes this is the only message which I am getting